# access premade functions with web-workers

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I'm currently creating an app where the user can apply filter on images. Anyway depending on the size of the image the script to apply a filter can take a long time. So I wanted to give workers a try.
(PHP is not an alternative btw)

So first I have my function that applies the filter, which works just fine(outside a worker).So Here's the code I have

The main javascript file, where I define the function and the worker:

```
jQuery(function ($)
{    

    var worker = "undefined";

    applyEffect();
    CreateWorker(worker);
});

//function to apply the effect stands here

/*-------------------*/
  /*WORKER*/
/*-------------------*/


//worker answers
function defineWorker(worker)
{
    worker.onmessage = function(e)
    {
        if(e.data == "msg from worker")
        {
          console.log(e.data);
        }
        worker.terminate();
  }
}


function CreateWorker(worker)
{
    $("#filters li").click(function clickWorker()
    {
        if (typeof worker == "undefined")
        {
            worker.terminate()
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("worker created");
        }
        worker = new Worker('js/worker.js');
        defineWorker(worker);
        worker.postMessage("hello"); // Start the worker.
    });
}
```

and here's the worker(worker.js):

```
self.onmessage = function(e)
{
    if(e.data == "hello")
    {
        applyFilter(Argument1,Argument2,function()
        {
            self.postMessage('msg from worker' + $(window).width());
        });
    }
}
```

When I try to start the worker via click, I get "ReferenceError: applyFilter is not defined"...same goes for jQuery-code: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

I kind of understand the problem here, but I don't know how to solve it.

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Each worker has it's own scope and no access to public functions like your applyFilter()-Method. It's the same with the libraries and the DOM. Workers have no DOM-Access, so i think u can't use them for your task here.

Give it a lick [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

A valid option would be to store the information of all images in an object and give this object to the worker. The worker itself then applies some tags or filters on the object and sends it back to the main-skript.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using camanJs for the filter, when I include the script via importScripts I get the error: "ReferenceError: window is not defined", so I guess I can't use worker here even if I use an object.

Comment: yep, because most of the window-methods aren't available. You can check the possible methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers

Comment: thanks, is there any other way to run the script in the background? like executing the script on the server and returning the data-URI?

Comment: well, at least you can try to write your own filter-methods as you need in a worker and send your objects to it (I guess that may be the most performant solution). Sure you can transfer all the data to a server, process it and send it back, but that costs ressources and time.

Comment: I'll look into it, maybe I just use php for the filters. It seems more fitting for the job :)